# Saving Entity state in time

Tags: database-design

we have a printing system which creates a document (invoices etc) and then prints them.
Because a document is around 4kb, we don't wan to actually store them.
We want to create them in time, however some of the variables used to create the document, may change at a later date, but we still need to be able to view the document as if it were the version from the past. For example, if a company changes bank, or address or even name, we don't want those changes reflecting past documents.

So, we are looking for a solution to save space, by creating documents as and when they are needed for viewing.

I have come up with a few ideas.

1) Save all needed variables at first creation time into a row (bank details etc) and use this row for report creation. Cons: Lots of repeated data (bank details don't change often)

2) Normalize like crazy, and have about 5 extra tables, with references to the pieces of data stored in the main row. Cons: Very... messy and a lot of work.

3) Store all history in time, lookup by date. So use the creation date to find the variables in the other tables at a point in time, by creating a copy of all data whenever a row changes. Con's still wastes some data every time someone makes a change.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well if you want to store old data - you are indeed going to use more storage... whether this is a 'waste' is a point for discussion if you need to do this... You can look into Slowly Changing Dimension tables to keep a history of all values. Storage is cheap, surely you won't worry about keeping changes to data? If you do worry - try having multi-tiered storage, where 'hot' most recent data is stored on fast storage and some cheap slow bulk storage keeps the 'cold' archived data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accuracy and performance need to be your primary concerns here.  Storage is a distant third.

EITHER store all of the values to populate the variables in the document (don't forget to include the version of the document)

OR version all of the sources of the variables and point to the version of each that was used in the document.  This would effectively be a slowly changing dimension.

The best option for you will depend on the ratio of documents to source data change.  My assumption is you will have far more documents for a bank than you will changes to the banks data.  In that case I think the second option is the most extensible, will have the best performance, and will likely use the least space long term.

Comment: I basically went with you EITHER option. I store all data needed in the table - a copy from other tables most of the time.